# xtype select multiple ModX

Tags: javascript, modx, extjs

Использую заготовку modExtra для быстрого создания ModX модуля, появилась потребность к одной записи присвоить несколько зависимостей. К примеру, есть парикмахерские услуги:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И есть таблица с мастерами оказывающих эти услуги.
Нужно в окне изменения/добавления услуг, добавить возможность выбора нескольких мастеров, оказывающих эту услугу.

Можно ли вывести **select multiple** в этом окне со список мастеров?
Далее, планирую в контроллере переносить зависимости в другую таблицу, где условно id_услуги = id_мастера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нашел дополнение http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/classic/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html , как его возможно подключить?

Comment: Никак. Это для 6.0.2 а у тебя 3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что тебе нужно называется SuperBoxSelect. Посмотреть реализацию для модикса можно в исходном коде [минишопа](https://github.com/bezumkin/miniShop2/blob/49bc08fa65562de30115d7f471c1d9bdc339b1ec/assets/components/minishop2/js/mgr/misc/ms2.combo.js#L232) или в дополнении [superboxselect 2](http://modx.com/extras/package/superboxselect).